# measuring statistics in java simulation

Tags: java, simulation, measurement

I have a group of nodes who send measurements to a bootstrap server. In the end I want the bootstrap server to sum all the measurements and write it to a file. One way to do that is to over-write the data to the file each time a measurement message is received(after summing up the current measurements). But this would be very inefficient. **I want to store the measurement data and write it to file only once after the simulation is completed.**

But the problem is that the simulator code that I am using is not under my control, its a library that I am using. So, I cant tell when exactly the simulation is going to end (and hence I cant tell which measurement message will be the last one).

I naively tried to store the measurement data in a static class but this data is not accessible when the simulation terminates. Is there any other way that I can do this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would find the last message using a timeout.

Write to disk if you have new data but you haven't got anything for a while e.g. a second.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot store the data you need in the process (which it seems you can't, since the static class failed), you need to persist the data some other way. To an on-disk file is one option, and another common one would be to a database.